# azure cache preview

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I tried the new azure preview that came with the new sdk on my computer.
I put a worker role with cache preview and put co-located role with 30% cache size.
on my controller i put this code:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        ViewBag.Id = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id;
        return View();
    }
```

now i ran the worker role via the emulator with 4 instances. the result was that every time i saw a different id - which mean the output cache never work with all the 4 instances ( to be clear i configure the output cache to work with the cache preview).

Only when i put an extra cache worker role as  dedicated role everything start to work like it should be.

My questions is:
Do i need the extra worker role to actually make the cache preview to work ok? - which mean the trade off of not working with azure appfabric cache is putting extra machine

Did i do something work and it should work with the web roles as co located roles?

thanks

edit:
this another section of my web.config

```
<dataCacheClients>
<tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Error" />
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="NugetTest" />
  <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

if my identifier have NugetTest ( which is my web roles - which i have 4) every time i switch machine i get a different cache. if i change the identifier to my worker role i get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add **applicationName** tag in the provider configuration in web.config of you app? If this is not added, instances will not share the cache across. Please note the **applicationName** tag.
This should be added for the web.config of webrole in **both dedicated or colocated cache scenario**.
Please reply if this solves your issue.

```xml
<caching>
  <outputCache defaultProvider="DistributedCache">
    <providers>
      <add name="DistributedCache" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="<cacheName>" applicationName ="<anyName>" dataCacheClientName="<dataCacheClientName>" />
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this issue. I always see the same instance, and I'm using Ctrl+F5 in the browser (thus rule out browser cache). PLease make sure you've configured output cache provider as described on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/.

```
<!-- If output cache content needs to be saved in a Windows Azure
     cache, add the following to web.config inside system.web. -->
<caching>
  <outputCache defaultProvider="DistributedCache">
    <providers>
      <add name="DistributedCache"
            type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheOutputCacheProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
            cacheName="default"
            dataCacheClientName="default" />
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: put an extra code in my question - the ctrl+F5 doesnt solve my issue. when i have 4 roles i always saw a different id instead of see the same one every time.